# Is it possible in vb.net to check, if the computer is connected via ethernet or over wireless?

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a simple programin vb.net that checks the connection method.
Maybe it's possible to check the cmd output, but I think that's a little bit to awkward. Is there any way to get it in a simple way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop all the network adapters and get the type of interface from each adapter:

```
Dim networkInterfaces As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()

For Each networkInterface As NetworkInterface In networkInterfaces
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} - Type: {1}", networkInterface.Name, networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType)
Next
```

Other similar SO/MSDN questions:

- [How to distinguish between Ethernet and WiFi IP Addresses using VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27843591/how-to-distinguish-between-ethernet-and-wifi-ip-addresses-using-vb-net)
- [How to identify if the Network Interface is LAN or Wifi or External](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753757/how-to-identify-if-the-network-interface-is-lan-or-wifi-or-external)
- [Ethernet Cable Check](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8c21fff7-adb5-47b2-bdde-c9196b19ca0e/ethernet-cable-check?forum=vbgeneral)